# How to Start new Activity on overlay item Tap in map?

Tags: android, android-maps

i have create map in app. i want to show check-ins in it. i am able to display Drawable in overlay item. but i want to start new Activity onTap that overlay item. is it possible?

Thank you... in advance....

Comment: are you using the default google maps api example?

Comment: http://developer.android.com/resources/tutorials/views/hello-mapview.html this page right?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes it is possible.

You have to override the below method where you have extended the `ItemizedOverlay<OverlayItem>`

```
@Override
protected final boolean onTap(int index) {
    //Do you job here.
}
```

Note: While starting activity you should have proper context.

Answer (score 2):

```
@Override
protected final boolean onTap(int index) {
         //Do you job here.
       startActivity(new Intent(ur_map_activity.this,SecondActivity.class));

}
```